# A word for someone who "imbues"

Tags: epithet-requests, derivational-morphology

I'm making a fantasy game, where one of the character classes is supposed to be called a "Arrow Imbuer". Yet it is marked with a red line on my PC, so I guess I'm writing a word incorrectly.

A short description of what an "Arrow Imbuer" does: a character that can imbue an arrow head with magical powers to deal extra damage.

Is there a word for someone who imbues something?

Comment: If you want to use *imbuer*, use *imbuer*.  It is a logical word-formation.

Comment: @Anonym I hesitated because it's marked as incorrect and english isn't my first language, so I wanted to check with people who know not to be ignorant. If you believe that "imbuer" is correct please post it as an answer! :)

Comment: Spelling an agentive form for _imbue_ would be a problem, since the _-er_ agentive suffix wants to attach to a consonant to form another syllable. So intrusive consonants are common; after all, the original Latin and P-I-E suffix was **-ter*; since the original form was _imbutus_, I'd imagine _imbutor_ would be correct. Or correct Latin, at least; the word is rare enough in English to make any formation from it pretty risky unless you're sure your audience is familiar with it.

Comment: To be understood at all, you will need to find a suitable synonym for *imbue* and use the agentive form of that word instead. ('agentive' is red-lined right here! that's another issue, of limited capabilities of spell-checkers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The agentive suffix *-er* can be applied to almost any verb to make an agent noun.  Even if the agent noun has not been invented yet, any native speaker will understand it if he knows the corresponding verb.  Currently existing examples include the following:

> *to fight* + *-er* = *fighter* 'one who fights'
>
> *to play* + *-er* = *player* 'one who plays'
>
> *to work* + *-er* = *worker* 'one who works'

Your invention, *imbuer*, also fits into this paradigm.  In fact, people have probably already been using the word for some time, albeit not enough for it to be included in every spell-checker's dictionary.

> *to imbue* + *-er* = *imbuer* 'one who imbues'

If you want to use it, use it!  Invention is the heart of language.

Comment: 'Invention' too needs to follow logic.

Comment: @Kris: no, invention doesn't need to follow logic any more than any other aspect of language formation needs to.  In terms of language formation invention just has to be cunning enough to not set off the alarm bells in the reader's or hearer's grammaticality-assessing apparatus.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark With that being said, invention usually *does* follow logic - a common pattern, a custom - of some kind.  Without that logic, no one could understand language at all.

Answer (score 3):

Consider **[endower](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/endower?r=66)**

*[Endow](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/endower?r=66)* means

> to furnish, as with some talent, faculty, or quality; equip: *Nature has endowed her with great ability.*

Comment: Close. However, it brings that financial/ monetary connotation with it, unlike *imbue's* fluid infusion.

Comment: @Kris The framers of the Declaration of Independence apparently didn't think so: *they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights*. (Yes, I get it. And yes, that was 240 years ago)

Comment: You might want to check out the new meta question about attributions.